# joomla 4 Blog category is not balanced correctly

Tags: php, html, foreach, joomla

I created a blog category from the menu. In Joomla 4 -> In Blog Layout -> Columns ، I can give a value to the column, but if we increase the value by one, the displayed contents are not balanced. And the "" did not close properly. After a general search, I realized that the contents are arranged as follows :
HTML :

```
     <div class="blog-items">
         <div class="blog-item">
             <div class="content">1</div>
             <div class="blog-item">
                 <div class="content">2</div>
             </div>
             <div class="blog-item">
                 <div class="content">3</div>
                 <div class="blog-item">
                     <div class="content">4</div>
                     <div class="blog-item">
                          <div class="content">5</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="blog-item">
                           <div class="content">6</div>         
                     </div>
                     <div class="blog-item">
                           <div class="content">7</div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

HTML The right way to be :

```
<div class="blog-items">
     <div class="blog-item"><div class="content">1</div></div>
     <div class="blog-item"><div class="content">2</div></div>
     <div class="blog-item"><div class="content">3</div></div>
     <div class="blog-item"><div class="content">4</div></div>
     <div class="blog-item"><div class="content">5</div></div>         
     <div class="blog-item"><div class="content">6</div></div>
     <div class="blog-item"><div class="content">7</div></div>
</div>
```

Note: When I disable "loadTemplate", the loop is displayed correctly and the divisions are closed correctly.
I also checked the information inside the "$this->loadTemplate('item')" but found no problem.
PHP :

```
<div class="blog-items">
    <?php foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) : ?>
        <div class="blog-item">
                <?php
                $this->item = & $item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item'); //Included <div class="content">value</div>
                ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

it's true,fixed.
All content had a  tag before page break,
You cannot insert it inside a div. The closing tag will be missing. Close the tag before inserting Read More.
Little did I know that using  before page break can be so destructive, and I've been looking for problems with PHP code for about a week now.